# serviceWorker.js requests from Safari 11 are flooding the server

Tags: javascript, safari, service-worker

Why is this happening 80 times in a row within 5 seconds:

```
my.domain.com:443 x.x.x.x - - [11/Apr/2018:06:08:18 +0200] "GET /serviceWorker.js HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "https://my.domain.com/serviceWorker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

my.domain.com:443 x.x.x.x - - [11/Apr/2018:06:08:18 +0200]
"GET /serviceWorker.js HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "https://my.domain.com/serviceWorker.js"
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

Content of serviceWorker.js:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function() {})
```

The code that registers the serviceWorker:

```
serviceWorker() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js').catch(() => {});
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You left the more interesting part of the code out – how does your SW registering code look like?

Comment: Added SW registering code @pate

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure you're not calling that multiple times? Like absolutely sure? Add some console logging inside your if conditional to make sure maybe?